# Making one jpeg file from 2 different images brought to user as 2 layers one under another

Tags: php

Let's suppose I have some div with picture.
Above this div there is another div with png picture of colored border , because of the fact that it is above the main picture colored borders are added to main picture so the user can see 1 picture with colored borders.

Now the problem is how can I join main picture file and colored borders png into 1 jpg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `imagick` extension, or can install it see here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-compositeimage.php
(Also can read [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) )

Otherwise with Gd
[PHP GD library used to merge two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428721/php-gd-library-used-to-merge-two-images)